# C# Unity Input Fields

Tags: c#, unity3d

В классе class_1 Есть несколько массивов класса InputField, которым я присвоил значения путём перетаскивания в Unity. Создаю два экземпляра классов class_2 в которые передаю значения инпут филдов - соответственно и массивы инпут филдов в два раза больше чем могли бы быть(первая половина для первого класса, вторая для воторого). Хотелось бы связывать классы инпут филдов с инпут филдами в юнити при создании экземпляра класса, что бы каждому новому экземпляру присвоить разные Unity инпут филды. Подскажите как это сделать?

UPDATE

Хм, ну попробую уточнить. Результат который я вижу в ходе реализации кода меня устраивает, но в ввиду возможных изменений хотелось бы изменить реализацию. 
Как бы объяснить то....) есть следующий конструктор класса -

```
public Weapon(InputField[] stat, Toggle[] toggle, InputField[] modifier)
```

конструктор присваивает полям типа double и int значения инпут филдов с помощью статического поля count в классе - вот так
    `dmg = double.Parse(stat[count++].text)`       и так далее.
При этом в начале и в конце конструктора существуют проверки на то, создавался ли второй экземпляр класса Weapon, вот такие в начале :

```
if (stat[0].text == "" && count == 0)    
            { count = 6; modCount = 4; }
```

и в конце:

```
if (stat[6].text == "" || count == stat.Length)
            { count = 0; modCount = 0;
```

Мне кажется что они лишние и можно было бы сделать как-то проще, так как если я решу сделать прогу где создаётся не 1-2 класса weapon, а больше, то прийдётся и эти проверки вечно переписывать и усложнять. Мне хотелось бы сделать присвоения инпут филдов Unity к классам InputField в коде как-то по другому. Что бы при случае увеличения\уменьшения кол-ва созданных классов weapon не приходилось переписывать проверки статических полей count.

Comment: По вашему описанию трудно понять, что вам нужно. Попробуйте начать не с описания возникшей проблемы, а с описания того, что вы хотите сделать с помощью своей реализации и какой результат хотите увидеть. Возможно, проблема не в реализации, а в целом в подходе к решению

Comment: Спасибо, добавил информацию к вопросу, надеюсь картинка стала более понятной )

Comment: ну, вы опять описываете свою реализацию) давайте попробую сам уточнить. Вы создаёте какие-то классы, которые хранят настройки для оружия? Т.е. каждый такой класс не хранит ссылок на филды и таглы, а хранит только значения урона, модификатора и ещё какого-то флага?

Comment: Верно, почти) 
Каждый класс не хранит ссылок на филды и таглы - да. 
Он хранит только значения характеристик оружия (скорострельность, урон, скорость перезарядки, криты и так далее - соответственно input[0], input[1], input[2] и так далее, так-же хранит метод расчета урона в зависимости от показателей. Значения модификаторов и таглов тоже не хранятся в классе - они учитываются в конструкторе класса при присвоении значения полям  характеристик - (урон, reload, crit и тд)